# Go to specific slide on click AnythingSlider

Tags: jquery, slider, anythingslider

I have a list of images and when one is clicked I access an anythingslider slideshow that is inside a fancybox popup.

HTML

```
<ul class="threeColGrid">
    <li>
        <div class="slideNumber">1</div>
        <div class="userStep">
            <img src="/upload/smb/support/folder/slide-1/howToStepOneImage.jpg#" onclick="$('a.magnifyStep').trigger('click'); return false;" alt="#" />
                <a class="magnifyStep" href="#userStepPopUp" ></a>
            <p>Downloaded&nbsp;<a title="#" href="/smb/support/how-to" target="_blank">software</a> from the website</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="slideNumber">2</div>
        <div class="userStep">
            <img src="/upload/smb/support/folder/slide-2/howToStepOneImageTwo.jpg#" onclick="$('a.magnifyStep').trigger('click'); return false;" alt="#" />
                <a class="magnifyStep" href="#userStepPopUp" ></a>
            <p>Connect your old device to your PC or laptop using a USB cable</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="slideNumber">3</div>
        <div class="userStep">
            <img src="/upload/smb/support/folder/slide-3/howToStepOneImageThree.jpg#" onclick="$('a.magnifyStep').trigger('click'); return false;" alt="#" />
                <a class="magnifyStep" href="#userStepPopUp" ></a>
            <p>Wait for software to recognise your device</p>
            <ul>
                <li>If your device is locked you may be asked to unlock your device&nbsp;</li>
                <li>If your device has not been registered previously you may need to set up your  options with your old device first</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="slideNumber">4</div>
        <div class="userStep">
            <img src="/upload/smb/support/how-to/folder/slide4/howToStepOneImageFour.jpg#" onclick="$('a.magnifyStep').trigger('click'); return false;" alt="#" />
                <a class="magnifyStep" href="#userStepPopUp" ></a>
            <p>From the device menu select Switch Devices</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="slideNumber">5</div>
        <div class="userStep">
            <img src="/upload/smb/support/how-to/folder/slide5/howToStepOneImageFive.jpg#" onclick="$('a.magnifyStep').trigger('click'); return false;" alt="#" />
                <a class="magnifyStep" href="#userStepPopUp" ></a>
            <p>Select your old device.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="slideNumber">6</div>
        <div class="userStep">
            <img src="/upload/smb/support/how-to/folder/slide6/howToStepOneImageSix.jpg#" onclick="$('a.magnifyStep').trigger('click'); return false;" alt="#" />
                <a class="magnifyStep" href="#userStepPopUp" ></a>
            <p>Select the data you would like to transfer to the new device and click on next.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$('#popUpslider').anythingSlider({
    buildArrows: true,
    buildStartStop: false,
    infiniteSlides: false,
    stopAtEnd: true,
    hashTags: true,
    easing: "swing"
});
```

This part works fine, but I now need to see a particular slide when one of the images is clicked (for example, clicking the 3rd image would open the fancybox window and show the 3rd slide inside anythingSlider).

Unfortunately I cant get this part to work. I'm using a CMS which dynamically populates the slider and add the hash to end of the image URL. Is there a way of targeting this hash, making the slider open at the clicked image?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brought to you directly from the [documentation](http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/) (Look for: Linking Directly To Slides from Static Links).

```
$("#slide-jump").click(function(e){
    $('.anythingSlider').anythingSlider(6);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any experience with AnythingSlider, but according to [the documentation](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/#&panel1-2), you can use the `startPanel` option when initializing. So if you want it to open to the third slide, use `startPanel:3`.

Comment: It's not the third slide that needs to open it any (depending on which image is clicked).

Comment: When you click on a slide, set a variable to that slide number, then use that variable instead of `3`.

Comment: +1 I think using the `startPanel` would be the way to do this, but you'd have to get a way to target the correct slide, maybe use a class name or alt name of the clicked image: `startPanel: $(this).attr('alt')` where the image alt has the slide `<img src="image3.jpg" alt="3">`

Comment: Unfortunately these methods aren't working for me at present. I think it may have something to do with fancybox being bound to the click events and for me, the anythingslider slideshow is simply opening on the first slide, or reopening to the last clicked slide.

Comment: @Mottie A colleague suggested a slightly different approach, which has worked perfectly.

`$(".userStep a").click(function(e){
var slideNumber = $(this).find('img').attr('alt');
$('#popUpslider').anythingSlider(slideNumber);
e.preventDefault();
});`

Comment: @webworker: If that's what worked for you, then you should post that as an answer and [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/147164), or you might just give the credit to gearsdigital since his answer is basically the same, just without the part of setting a variable.